# Why do the new version(s) of jQuery not work with this recursion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, recursion

I ran into a (bug?) with the newest versions of jQuery today where my recursion loop animating background position no longer works. Please see this example:

(this is working with version 1.9)
http://codepen.io/bonpixel/pen/qLkgt

Delete the cdn jquery and use the codepen bootstrap jquery (version 1.10.0) and it no longer loops. I saw the same results with jquery 2.0.1. It almost seems like it's specifically an issue with -= or += that i am using for the background positioning? Its as though the value used to calculate the new position is not updated after (or during) the animation.

Any thoughts?

**(edit adding static code)**

HTML

```
<div class="blue"><div>
```

CSS

```
.blue{
  width: 100px;
  height: 190px;
  background: transparent;url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-6xJXVFMdC64/TckciX_eI7I/AAAAAAAAAEc/IYORj5mZXiY/s1600/wlk01.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

JS

```
var backgroundSlidingLeft = function () {
  $('.blue').animate({
    'background-position-x': '-=100px',
    'background-position-y': '0px'
  }, 1000, 'linear', backgroundSlidingLeft);
};
backgroundSlidingLeft();
```

Comment: It's a known bug on the lastest versions: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939

Comment: Always include all relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Thanks @darkajax. I didn't know what it was specifically but that answers it.

Comment: @Privateer Sadly it seems it hasn't been fixed, let's hope it is soon...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder what's the standard way to include html css and javascript while providing some sort of context about how the code is working together? Or does only only include the JS and expect someone to internalize the rest? I understand the point, and will do in the future, but I figured detached html, css and js is not exactly helpful. Perhaps StackOverflow needs their own codepen or jsfiddle in house? :)

Comment: @Privateer: Your best bet at present is to include it in the question (not in the future, **now** using the "edit" link), **and** optionally on a live site such as http://jsbin.com, http://jsfiddle.net, http://codepen.io...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@darkajax answered it completely via bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939

"Relative animation (using += or -=) is broken in 1.10.0."

Thanks!